# What type of color should I use to color my shoes?

Tags: painting, color

I want to color my old shoes but I'm not sure what type of color will be long lasting, so the color won't be washed away when it rains or when I wash them.

Comment: Without knowing what they're made of this question will be basically impossible to answer. Are they leather? suede? fabric? plastic? If you can update your question to include this information, along with a picture of your shoes, you might get an answer.

Answer (score 4):

[Shoe dye](https://www.timpson.co.uk/shoe-care/shoe-dye.html) exists, in versions for leather and suede.  They should work reasonably well on natural fibres but the effect on synthetic fibres is less reliable (try applying, leaving to dry, then rinsing well).  Any plastic (e.g. vinyl) bits won't take dye.

Overall it's crucial to know what your shoes are made of before you start.